# Yii2.0 extending DbManager

Tags: php, namespaces, yii2

I am trying to extend the **DbManager** in order to set my own table names for  `$itemTable`, `$itemChildTable` and `$assignmentTable`.

Sadly I don't know how to add my new folder of myComponents to the namespace, and I don't want to create it under the same folder as the other in case I need to upgrade the framework.

Anyone added an other folder for namespaces to **Yii2.0** ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to be in the same namespace, as long as you correctly specify the class namespace "path" when you update the configuration.

If you have added the new folder under the common part, the class path for your DbManager would be `common\myComponents\DbManager`. As said, if then correctly update the config, you should be set.

Comment: Common folder is only on the advance template. I can create the same one but it is not going to be load. Any idea on where in the config file it should be added the folder ?

Comment: The folders that get loaded are simply determined by what configuration files you include in your bootstrap files (index.php usually). I only suggested common because it seems you can use that db manager every but you're just as free in adding it to the frontend or whatever.